# When we use notifyListeners in ChangeNotifier?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, flutter-change-notifier

Why we use sometimes notifyListeners and also why we do not use notifyListeners? How can we use a function in changenotifier ?

For instance, in this code, sometimes we used to notifyListeners, but sometimes we did not use notifyListeners (in login() function). Why ? When we use notifyListeners?

```
String get userEmail => _userEmail;

  set userEmail(String value) {
    _userEmail = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get userPassword => _userPassword;

  set userPassword(String value) {
    _userPassword = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get userName => _userName;

  set userName(String value) {
    _userName = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  DateTime get dateOfBirth => _dateOfBirth;

  set dateOfBirth(DateTime value) {
    _dateOfBirth = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> login() async {
    try {
      isLoading = true;

      print(userEmail);
      print(userPassword);

      if (isLogin) {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: userEmail,
          password: userPassword,
        );
      } else {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: userEmail,
          password: userPassword,
        );
      }

      isLoading = false;
      return true;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      isLoading = false;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Besides can someone answer me about why we use set method in this code

```
  bool get isLogin => _isLogin;

  set isLogin(bool value) {
    _isLogin = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `notifyListeners()` is used whenever you want to trigger a rebuild or whenever there is an active listener which is monitoring for the change to perform certain actions

Assume a scenario, You have a data model, and as soon as you fetch the data from APIs you want to parse it and fill in the model class, Also you want that UI will automatically rebuild after getting the data !

For this purpose you can use `notifyListeners()` in data class and in your UI code, You can wrap the parts which needs to be rebuild with a `ChangeNotifierProvider` or a `Consumer` Widget that will monitor for changes and as soon as they encounter any change , They will rebuild the underlying Widget(s).

In the code you shared above, You've used `private` fields that cannot be accessed outside of this file and you are using `getters` and `setters` to basically retrieve them and modify them

Answering your last question now,
We use `set` method or `setter` to basically update or modify a value (generally a private value)

Just to provide you some additional info,
You should **NOT** wrap fields in getters and setters just to be "safe".
This method is Old and not needed in Dart language

You can read more about this [here](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_getters_setters.html)

You can also read about getters and setters in dart [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#getters-and-setters).

Since you are new to StackOverflow, I welcome you.
Happy Fluttering !

Comment: i figure out now. So if i want to update UI,then i have to use notifylisteners i suppose right?